# Read every line of file in bash and awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file(test.txt) which has contents like

```
/the/path/foo.txt  foo.txt 
/the/paths/doo.txt  doo.txt 
/the/path/foo.pl  foo.pl 
/the/paths/doo.pl  doo.pl 
/the/path1/soo.csv  soo.csv
/the/path2/moo.csv  moo.csv
```

I want to have awk {print $1} be saved to a variable1 and awk {print $2} be saved to variable2 in bash script i.e variable1 gets /the/path/foo.txt and variable2 gets foo.txt and so on

Thanks

Comment: Define "and so on". What and where do you do things with line2?

Comment: Check the command "read" in the bash manual pages: read variable1 variable2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `read` built-in to capture and assign fields to variables (assuming there are no spaces in your paths):

```
while read -r var1 var2; do
    # do something with variables
done < text.txt
```

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)